# Inner join with if statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, inner-join

I am trying to build the following sp :

```
USE [MarMoniApp]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Desc_by_date]    Script Date: 10/23/2012     09:01:40 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Desc_by_date]
@DateToSearch varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
select a.ticker,a.First_T, a.Last_T, a.Size_mln, a.pct_d_vol,a.a_trad,a.coolname,a.recency,b.Analyst
from Order_Desc a

CASE
When a.coolname = 'ELTORO'
then (Inner join MarMoniApp.dbo.Namelist b on a.ticker = b.ticker )
END

where convert(datetime, cast(rtrim(First_T) AS nvarchar)) > DateToSearch 
order by  CONVERT(DATETIME, cast(rtrim(First_T) AS nvarchar) )  DESC
END
```

I want to do the inner join only if the "coolname" is equal to eltoro, but it seems that my syntax is not correct.

Comment: what columns do you want to get from table `Namelist`?

Comment: it seems confusing. can you elaborate more, for instance if `a.coolname <> 'ELTORO'`, what are the columns you want to get? and if equal?

Comment: i've seen `b.Analyst` is included in your query but you want to conditionally join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about making two select statement and then union them.

```
select ... from Order_Desc a
Inner join MarMoniApp.dbo.Namelist b on a.ticker = b.ticker
where a.coolname = 'ELTORO' AND ...

union

select ... from Order_Desc a
where a.coolname != 'ELTORO' AND ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use **Left Outer Join** as below:

```
select a.ticker,a.First_T, a.Last_T, a.Size_mln, a.pct_d_vol,a.a_trad,a.coolname,a.recency,b.Analyst
from Order_Desc a
LEFT OUTER JOIN MarMoniApp.dbo.Namelist b
on a.ticker = b.ticker
**where 
(   
    (a.coolname <> 'ELTORO')
    OR
    (a.coolname = 'ELTORO' AND a.ticker = b.ticker)
)** 
AND convert(datetime, cast(rtrim(First_T) AS nvarchar)) > DateToSearch 
order by  CONVERT(DATETIME, cast(rtrim(First_T) AS nvarchar) )  DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need something like:

```
INNER JOIN
 MarMoniApp.dbo.Namelist b 
ON 
 a.coolname = 'ELTORO'
 AND a.ticker = b.ticker
```

Basically -- you cannot do conditional JOIN. You can only select rows to JOIN.

If you need columns from `MarMoniApp.dbo.Namelist` table only if `a.coolname = 'ELTORO'` use `LEFT JOIN` instead.

Another option (i.e. in case of performance is the key) is to use `UNION ALL` as [@Turcia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/172412/turcia) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13025696/1483) (use NULL as value of extra column for part without `JOIN`).

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am working mostly with postgres and mysql so I don't know the CASE-syntax... But, the way I read your SQL, I would have written the part from the "CASE" as

```
WHERE 
Inner join MarMoniApp.dbo.Namelist b on a.ticker = b.ticker and a.coolname='ELTORO')
and convert(datetime, cast(rtrim(First_T) AS nvarchar)) > DateToSearch 
order by  CONVERT(DATETIME, cast(rtrim(First_T) AS nvarchar) )  DESC
```

(but of cource, I may have misunderstood the idea of the CASE-syntax)